# How do I get related entity nested in linq to entities? Survey questions, subquestions, and options

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am completely new to LINQ-to-SQL and LINQ-to-Entities. I have a service set up that returns json. I am having trouble finding out how to return nested or projected content (not sure which one I need). Right now I have the question data returning fine with no nesting.

This is my code.

```
public List<Question> GetQuestionsByGymID(string gymID)
{
    // Question class is translated structure from GymQuestionEntities
    List<Question> questionList = new List<Question>();
    int intid;
    bool result = int.TryParse(gymID, out intid);
    using (var context = new SurveyEntities())
    {
        var questionEntity = 
            from p in context.GymQuestionsEntities
            join o in context.QuestionTypeEntities
            on p.QuestionType equals o.ID
            join n in context.SurveyQuestionEntities
            on p.Question equals n.ID
            where p.Gym == intid
            select new Question
            {
                ID = p.ID,
                Gym = p.Gym,
                Section = p.Section,
                QuestionSequence = p.QuestionSequence,
                Instruction = p.Instruction,
                QuestionType = o.Type,
                QuestionID = p.Question,
                QuestionText = n.QuestionText,
                parentQuestion = p.parentQuestion,
                isRequired = p.isRequired,
                isMatrix = p.isMatrix,
                MatrixFloor = p.MatrixFloor,
                MatrixCeiling = p.MatrixCeiling,
            };
        foreach (var Entity in questionEntity)
        {
            if (Entity != null)
                questionList.Add(Entity);
        }
    }
    return questionList;
}

// this method returns empty page. I have no idea how to debug this.
public List<QuestionWithOptions> GetQuestionsWithOptionsByGymID(string gymID)
{
    int intid;
    bool result = int.TryParse(gymID, out intid);
    List<QuestionWithOptions> questionList = new List<QuestionWithOptions>();
    List<Question> Questions = GetQuestionsByGymID(gymID);
    using (var context = new UTourEntities())
    {

        var questionWithOption = from p in context.GymQuestionsEntities.Include("QuestionOptions").Include("OptionChoices")
                                 join o in context.QuestionTypeEntities
                                 on p.QuestionType equals o.ID
                                 join n in context.SurveyQuestionEntities
                                 on p.Question equals n.ID
                                 where p.Gym == intid
                                 select new QuestionWithOptions
                                 {
                                     ID = p.ID,
                                     Gym = p.Gym,
                                     Section = p.Section,
                                     QuestionSequence = p.QuestionSequence,
                                     Instruction = p.Instruction,
                                     QuestionType = o.Type,
                                     QuestionID = p.Question,
                                     QuestionText = n.QuestionText,
                                     parentQuestion = p.parentQuestion,
                                     isRequired = p.isRequired,
                                     isMatrix = p.isMatrix,
                                     MatrixFloor = p.MatrixFloor,
                                     MatrixCeiling = p.MatrixCeiling,
                                     QuestionOptions = p.QuestionOption
                                 };
        foreach (var Entity in questionWithOption)
        {
            if (Entity != null)
                questionList.Add(Entity);

        }
    }
    return questionList;
    // StackOverflow_Answer
    // return null;
}
```

This is what my entities look like:
[image: EntityModel]
Here is hand-jammed example of what I am trying to return.
I took a shortcut and included OptionChoiceEntity data (the text of the option) into the QuestionOptionEntity (maps questions to options) object.

```
{
    ID: 4,
    Gym: 8,
    Section: 1,
    QuestionSequence: 4,
    QuestionType: "Heading",
    parentQuestion: null,
    QuestionID: 4,
    QuestionText: "What are some areas of interest?",
    Instruction: null,
    ChildQuestions: 
    {
        ID: 5,
        Gym: 8,
        Section: 1,
        QuestionSequence: 5,
        QuestionType: "Checkbox",
        parentQuestion: 4,
        QuestionID: 5,
        QuestionText: "Aquatics",
        Instruction: null,
        QuestionOption:
        {
            ID: 2,
            Question: 5,
            OptionSequence: 1,
            OptionChoice: "Swimming",
            isOther: false          
        },
        {
            ID: 3,
            Question: 5,
            OptionSequence: 2,
            OptionChoice: "Lessons",
            isOther: false
        }
        isRequired: false,
        isMatrix: false,
        MatrixFloor: null,
        MatrixCeiling: null
    },
    QuestionOption:
    {
        ID: 1,
        Question: 4,
        OptionSequence: 1,
        OptionChoice: "Other",
        isOther: true
    }
    isRequired: false,
    isMatrix: false,
    MatrixFloor: null,
    MatrixCeiling: null
},
```

Comment: Updated code to show what I have tried with .Include function (2nd method). Also I'm working with a black box here because it doesn't show up in WCF Test Client. Is the best way to debug, going to be to remove the WebInvoke method from my service and work in test client?

Comment: Using breakpoints I can see that my GetQuestionsWithOptionsByGymID method is returning QuestionWithOptions items that get added to the list with their included QuestionOptions, but still it shows up blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include the subentities you can use the "Include" method :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx

Regarding the end json result, you could mark your entities as being Serializable and use DataContractJsonSerializer to serialize them as json.

Comment: having trouble with include. I will update code. The json part is working fine.